# How to initialise an abstract in Julia?

Tags: julia

```
Julia> abstract Shape
ERROR: syntax: extra token "Shape" after end of expression
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[64]:0
```

**Just wanted to create an abstract but it says following even when I use help?>
Is there any alternate to this?**

```
help?> abstract
search: AbstractSet abstract type AbstractChar AbstractDict AbstractFloat

Couldn't find abstract
Perhaps you meant struct or AbstractSet
  No documentation found.

  Binding abstract does not exist.
```

Comment: Where are you getting your Julia syntax? Seems like you might be looking at some very old documentation?

Comment: I bought a course at Udemy, "Getting started with julia" it's a little outdated but seems to work fine for most parts..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is `abstract type Shape end`.

You can find the docs in the REPL help mode with the full keyword:

```
help?> abstract type
```

There is [online documentation on the keyword](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#abstract%20type) and more [general documentation on types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/).